# How not to kill a subprocess opened by another process in python?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, kill-process

I would like from a python script to run a program that I developed in python too. However I would like to kill my script, but not the program that I opened for it.

I am opening my program for a subprocess like this:

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(
    [python_path, "-m", "myprogram", "start"],
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
    stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w')
)
```

Both run perfectly, however when I kill my script, my program is killed together. Would there be any way to prevent my program from being finalized together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a problem with Windows. When a signal is given to kill the script, that signal is passed through to the subprocess, which is myprogram. A way to solve it is including "creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP" as parameter on list of Popen.

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(
    [python_path, "-m", "myprogram", "start"],
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
    stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
)
```

Windows passes the sign to all processes in the same group, so adding "creationflags" will create a new group for myprogram, and it will not be killed when you wants to kill only the script.